# How to override web.config customErrors settings at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, runtime, custom-errors

I have the following code in the **web.config** file for my ASP.NET C# app that's hosed on Azure:

```
<!-- Turn on Custom Errors -->
<!-- Switch the mode to RemoteOnly for Retail/Production -->
<!-- Switch the mode to On for to see error pages in the IDE during development -->
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
   <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorPage403.aspx"/>
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

This works great for errors when I'm hitting my site site natively (http://ipredikt.com/ErrorPage.aspx), but I also have a Facebook version of the app in which all of the pages use a different MasterPage and hence a different URL (http://ipredikt.com/ErrorPageFB.aspx).

Is it possible to **modify the customError redirect values at runtime** when I'm running in Facebook app mode, as if I had the following settings in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPageFB.aspx">
   <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorPage403FB.apx"/>
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage404FB.apx"/>
</customErrors>
```

I don't think I can set this at the Application scope since it's individual **pages** in my app that have knowledge of whether they are running in Facebook mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a brute force solution. I'm using this on the page for the non-Facebook mode 404 errors:

```
  protected override void OnInit(System.EventArgs e)
  {         
     // If the user tries, for example, to navigate to" /fb/foo/bar
     // then the Request.Url.Query will be as follows after the 404 error: ?aspxerrorpath=/fb/foo/bar
     string queryString = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Query;

     string[] str = queryString.Split('=');

     if (str.Length > 0)
     {
        string[] str2 = str[1].Split('/');

        if (str2.Length > 1)
        {
           string test = str2[1].ToLowerInvariant();

           if (test == "fb")
           {
              string pathAndQuery = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
              string absolutePath = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

              string mungedVirtualPath = pathAndQuery.Replace(absolutePath, "/ErrorPage404FB.aspx");

              Response.Redirect(mungedVirtualPath);
           }
        }
     }

     base.OnInit(e);
  }
```

Hardly ideal, but it works.

Comment: Change Server.Transfer() to Response.Redirect() since we want the munged URL to be visible. Server.Transfer honors the new URL but displays the original one.

Answer (score 1):

"Facebook mode" seems like something you could track in Session, which would be accessible in ErrorPage.aspx to trigger a transfer to ErrorPageFB.aspx.

Update - you can clean up your brute-force solution quite a bit by using `Request.QueryString`:

```
protected override void OnInit(System.EventArgs e)
{         
    // If the user tries, for example, to navigate to" /fb/foo/bar
    // then the Request.Url.Query will be as follows after the 404 error: ?aspxerrorpath=/fb/foo/bar
    var requestedPath = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["aspxerrorPath"];

    if (requestedPath.StartsWith("/fb/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var requestedUrl = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        var pathAndQuery = requestedUrl.PathAndQuery;
        var absolutePath = requestedUrl.AbsolutePath;

        var mungedVirtualPath = pathAndQuery.Replace(absolutePath, "/ErrorPage404FB.aspx");

        Response.Redirect(mungedVirtualPath);
    }

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Does `Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request` actually return a different instance than simply `Request`?

Comment: So you're saying I should just let the redirect from web.config occur, and then do another redirect or a server.transfer() from ErrorPage.aspx if I'm in Facebook mode?

Comment: Actually, we don't use Session at all in our app. It's turned off, so that's not an option for us.

Comment: Hi look at my suggestion below you can check the URL referrer and then decide if you want to do the redirect to a new error page

Comment: So how do you track which master page should be shown across multiple requests?

Comment: The requests from the Facebook app will always be of the form: http://apps.facebook.com/ipredikt/fb/... I will have ASP.NET routing in place that will map this request to: defaultfb.aspx.  That page, in turn, knows it's a Facebook page, so it sets the appropriate "IsFacebookPage" variables for the all the ASCX controls that build up the UI. As I noted, it's the pages themselves that know if they are Facebook-mode pages, so I can't set this at the Application scope.

Comment: Maybe `Page_Error()` is an option, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx#customerrors_topic5

Comment: I thought about page error, but the problem is that the some error won't occur on a page. For example, I can force a 404 by navigating to a non-existent page like http://ipredikt.com/fb/foo/bar/zappa. So there's no page at all in this example.

Comment: Could your 404 page inspect the requested URL and adjust accordingly if it sees `/fb/`?

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing. See my solution below. I've actually got a static utility method now since this "fix" is used on several different page (general error, 404, and 403).

Comment: The code in the brute force example contains some code I needed for ASP.NET routing, so for that I had to use: Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request. I'm still trying to decide whether to use routing for the ErrorPages or keep the ASP.NET generated QueryString intact.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think what you can do is make another redirect inside your custom error page acording to the referrer - Request.UrlReferrer sometime the referrer is null so make sure you deal with that

Comment: See comment below about UrlReferrer being null.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is using session but if you don't use session on you website you can always use cookie and when the user arrive to the error page examine the cookie and decide if you want to redirect him to a new error page

Comment: Man, this sure seems like a lot of work to display a Facebook specific version of an error page.

Comment: UrlReferrer isn't available. It's null. I'm guessing this is because of the setting in web.config. Looks like the only strings that give me a clue are based on: Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.  I get back: http://localhost:3737/ErrorPage404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/fb/foo/bar So I can look at the value for "aspxerrorpath", split it on "/", and see if element zero is "fb".  Then do Server.Transfer if it is.